# File upload with jQuery: Empty FormData Values

Tags: jquery, ajax

**Hello Stackoverflow.**

I currently have an issue and I can't find out what's the issue. I've created file uploaders using AJAX earlier, and none of them had the following issue. The value of the file input stays empty. I've tried it in two ways.

First I submitted the whole form with `formData(this)`. This worked partially. My other inputs got sent to the script which handles the file. However, the file input was not. Even if it was in the same form, it just didn't get submitted with it.

Now I'm trying to it as follows;

```
  $("#form").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('customer', document.getElementById("customer").value);
        formData.append('owner', document.getElementById("owner").value);
        formData.append('uploaded_file', document.getElementById("upload").files[0]);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data:  formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
                var rtrn = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(rtrn.return = "false")
                {
                    useGGA.createAlert(rtrn.message, rtrn.return, 7500);
                }
                else
                {
                    useGGA.createAlert(rtrn.message, rtrn.return, 7500);
                    $("#form")[0].reset();
                }
            },
            error: function()
            {
                useGGA.createAlert("Something went wrong!", "false", 7500);
            }
        });
    }));
```

However. Here I have the same issue. `#upload` just stays empty. This is my HTML;

```
 <form id="form" action="api/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
      <input type="text" name="owner" id="owner" value="<?= $this->model->data['owner'] ?>" readonly>
      <input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" value="<?= $this->werkstatt->data['ad_id'] ?>" readonly>    
      <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="upload">
      <input type="submit" class="__submit_green __launch_upload" value="Ausführen">
</form>
```

When I now run the following in the console; `document.getElementById("upload").files[0]`, it returns me `Cannot read property 'files' of null`. The same happens when just submitting the form.

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: Do not include `#` in `#upload`. The `#` tells a css selector that what follows is an id, but for a function like `getElementById` the function already knows that the parameter is an element ID. Just use `document.getElementById("upload")` to get the element.

Comment: remove `#` if you're using `document.getElementById` it already know that it's an id, you use that with `document.querySelector`

Comment: Thanks, but this was just a typo from me on stackoverflow. I've edited it by now.